# Javascript can't create dictionary in IE

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

```
var Dictionary = {
foo: "bar"
}

alert(Dictionary.foo)
```

This works fine in Firefox 6, but not in IE8, is there a syntax error that FF is displacing, or do I need an IE fix?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jdb1991/JR3uH/

Comment: What isn't working?  Is the alert not firing, or is it firing but not showing "foo"?  Are there any other objects in the page called "Dictionary" (such as a dictionary plugin) or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example does work in IE8 - at least for me. I'm running on a Windows XP SP 3 with the latest IE8.

If you have problems with some Object-notations, check if your key is named like keywords which are specified in JavaScript, like `class` and aren't defined as a String (you need to write it as `"class"`. Otherwise missing colons are often a source of errors.

Comment: Please check the jsfiddle I've attached.  For me, that's not working on IE8.

Comment: Also, which keywords are banned?  I'm using `Display` as one which is failing

Comment: I tried your JSFiddle example and as stated above it works for me - i get an alert with "bar" in it. Have you tried some other code which didn't work and is now in your cache or something (i know, i know...)? Keywords for JavaScript are as example stated here: [Keywords](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm)

Comment: Yeah, jsfiddle must have been playing up; I've run it again and it's worked.  I don't appear to be using any of the reserved key words.  Let me check again and I'll show you code if I need to.

Comment: http://forumsblogswikis.com/2008/07/21/javascript-error-expected-identifier-string-or-number-in-ie/

Comment: Was a tailing comma, removed which fixed.  Thanks for the help.